# How to put the selected element through id into an input

Tags: java, spring, maven, jsp, jsp-tags

I have something like this:

```
<select id="select_object_id">
  <c:forEach items="{map.items}" var='item'>
     <option value="${item.getName()}"
        <c:if test='item.getName() eq item1'>selected</if>
     >${item.getName()}</option>
  </c:forEach>
</select>
<input type="text" id="myInput" value="select_objet_id.getSelectedItem.getName()"/>
```

I would like to know how to get the selected element of the select and use it on the input calling it trought its id.

Thanks

Comment: On which event do you want the input value to change?

Comment: On the submit of the form